# If $S$ is a sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $H \lhd G$ and $S\subset H$, how to show that if $S$ is normal in $H$ then its normal in $G$?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be some finite group.

If $S$ is a sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $H$ normal subgroup of $G$ and $S\subset H$, how to show that if $S$ is normal in $H$ then its normal in $G$?

Comment: This is because normal Sylow $p$-subgroups are characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that all Sylow subgroups for a given prime are conjugated, so

$$S\le H\stackrel{\text{since}\;H\lhd G}\implies S^x\le H^x=H\implies$$

all the Sylow $p$ - subgroups of $\;G\;$ (i.e., $\;\{S^x\;:\;x\in G\}\;$) are contained in $\;H\;$ , and since $\;H\;$ has **only one** Sylow $\;p$ - subgroup ( because $\;S\lhd H\;$) , then $\;S=S^x\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in G\iff\;G\;$ has one unique Sylow subgroup